# return renderview instead of return view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am used to:

```
public ActionResult CreateSomething()
{
    return View("ViewName", new CreateSomeDto());
}
```

I just encountered this in some legacy code:

```
   public ActionResult CreateSomething()
    {
        return RenderView("ViewName", new CreateSomeDto());
    }
```

Could someone please explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RenderView()` is an antiquated method from MVC 1.0

The ViewEngine was less sophisticated. Controller methods did not return `ActionResults`. In fact, they returned `void`. A `RenderView` call does not return a string, but rather "renders" or writeln's the view into place.

It's functionality is very similar to the way `Html.RenderPartial()`'s are rendered into a View.

Comment: Mmmh ... 'partial' rings a bell. Could this be related to ajax/javascript? My problem is, that the get request hits the CreateSomething action but the front end page which contains a link for the get request does not change at all - maybe the routing is screwed up. Anyway, I presume I could safely replace RenderView with View?

Comment: @csetzkorn Since you're using a more recent version of MVC and your action method returns an ActionResult, you can simply return a View.